# Get time from database and compare

Tags: php

I want to get time from database then use it to compare with current time. How can i do it?

```
$timeStart = $row['timeStart'];
echo 'Time Start : '.$timeStart;
echo "</br>";
$time_offset =ICT; // Change this to your time zone
$time_a = ($time_offset * 120);
$time = date("M-d-Y H:i:s",time() + $time_a);
echo 'Current time is : '.$time;
echo "</br>";
if ($timeStart + $timeForEachDownload > $time) $totalDownload = $totalDownload + 1;
```

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: What's the output of this script? What is `$row['timeStart']`? Is it a MySQL datetime value like `2010-11-19 11:59:00`, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if ($timeStart + $timeForEachDownload > $time)
     $totalDownload = $totalDownload + 1;
```

To this:

```
if ((strtotime($timeStart) + strtotime($timeForEachDownload)) > $time)
     $totalDownload = $totalDownload + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry i have tried. But it is not work:(. Time in my table of database is 2010-11-18 22:41:52 and 2010-11-18 00:00:00. When i run code and echo dbtime & curren_time it displayed :               12900 94912

12900 13200

Comment: That number that you get is the number of seconds since epoch. Try this: echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dbtime) . ' ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_time) it converts that number into a readable format.

Comment: I tried with format of date likes : echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_time); The result displayed                       2010-11-18 22:41:52
2010-11-19 09:46:47
2010-11-18 00:00:00
2010-11-19 09:46:47

Comment: YES. It works. I paste your code into. But this command if($dbtime > $curren_time) wrong because curren_time is not define. :)). So funny. Thanks